# ASP.Net Core Post Access Denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm currently making an e-commerce website in ASP.Net Core. I've ran into a little dilemma. I go to add a product, fill out the form, and then when I try to submit the form it brings up my 404/access page.

This is in production mode on an Ubuntu 16.04 web server. Testing locally, it works fine.

The code:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddProduct()
{
    return View(new ProductAddModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddProduct(ProductAddModel model, IFormFile file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/images/Products", file.FileName);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }

        var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
        ProductDataModel dataModel = new ProductDataModel()
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            ShortDescription = model.ShortDescription,
            Description = model.Description,
            Category = model.Category,
            Game = model.Game,
            Price = model.Price,
            ImagePath = file.FileName,
            DeveloperUserId = user.Id
        };
        context.Products.Add(dataModel);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Products", "Admin");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Here are a few screenshots.
[Add Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg6AW.png)
[404/Access Denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlDQS.png)

Comment: Issue could be related to write permissions on `Products` directory. For confirmation you can put the `file.CopyToAsync` in `try catch block` and then check if the product is added successfully in database

Comment: Please show the route for POST action

Comment: You say, it's 404! That Means 'Not found' and is not an access error.

Comment: @PoulBak, well I combined the 404 page with the access denied page. I understand that 404 means not found...

Comment: @RomanMarusyk, the route is the default. "[controller]/[action]".

Comment: For `Page not found/Access denied!`, it seems to be custom error message. Share us the code which you define this error. To check whether it is permission or not found, comment out the content for `AddProduct(ProductAddModel model, IFormFile file)`, will it throw any error?

Comment: @TaoZhou, I actually found the issue. "System.IO.IOException: Permission denied." How would I go about adjusting this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are including the file in the form? So the file is in the model, so it wont find the route. Add the IFormFile in the model:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddProduct(ProductAddModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/images/Products", model.File.FileName);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
           await model.File.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }

        var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
        ProductDataModel dataModel = new ProductDataModel()
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            ShortDescription = model.ShortDescription,
            Description = model.Description,
            Category = model.Category,
            Game = model.Game,
            Price = model.Price,
            ImagePath = model.File.FileName,
            DeveloperUserId = user.Id
        };
        context.Products.Add(dataModel);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Products", "Admin");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

If this doesnt work, pls show you Startup.cs and the AddProduct.cshtml

Comment: Hello, if you look above, I am including the IFormFile.

Comment: @AveryShaw you are including the IFormFile as an seperate parameter. Add it in the Model.

Comment: I read the response wrong. Anyway, I found the issue. "System.IO.IOException: Permission denied."